# Excel: Create scatter plots based on functions?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a dataset comprising the pay for a number of employees in my company. I am creating a scatter plot to show the annual pay for each person. The X axis is the age, the Y axis is the annual pay. I have two series, one for men and one for women.

For now, I am selecting the groups manually, but I would much rather use a function to achieve this - particularly because I am creating another scatter plot that has a series for men and women for each department.

Comment: Generate a new table and use filters?